# Define the linear transformation $T: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Define the linear transformation $\Bbb R^3\longrightarrow \Bbb R^2$ via,

$T\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}y+z\\y-z\end{bmatrix}.$

---

I'm just a bit confused on the question. When it asks to define the linear transformation, does this just mean proving the two basic rules that $T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v)$ and  $T(cu) = cT(u)$? Finding the standard matrix? Or is there something bigger to this that I am missing? Thanks in advance.

The second part asks to find all vectors which map to 0.

Comment: Is this the actual question? Are you sure that this isn't the definition of some linear transformation that you will later use in an exercise?

Comment: @RichardMcCormick The question is not well posed on its own. If nothing else is given, your doubts are legitimate. It seems like the question is incomplete... The transformation is given but no question is asked.

Comment: We have defined a transformation $T\colon \Bbb R^3\rightarrow \Bbb R^2$. Now what are we supposed to show about $T$? I suppose, we need to show that $T$ is linear? And to compute its kernel and image? It clearly has a non-trivial kernel.

Comment: This is the entire question in full. My professor wrote up his own homework questions and there are 3 or 4 more exactly like this.

Comment: I doubt it is the formulation of your professor (for example, a "comma" after "via" is unusual). Also the $T$ is misplaced. Perhaps someone copied it and forgot the second part? Do you have a link to the original question?

Comment: Oh my bad, there is a second part. This is the first part, the second asks to find all vectors that map to 0.

Comment: So it's about finding the kernel of $T$ as I said.

Comment: You professor already defined this linear transformation for you, and you need to use the definition and do whatever else you are asked to do.

Answer (score 5):

When mathematical texts say

> Define the linear transformation $\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^2$ via
> $$
> T\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}y+z\\y-z\end{bmatrix}
> $$

what they are really saying is that they establish a linear transformation from $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R^2$, give it the name $T$, and its behavior is described by the given formula.

It is not, on its own, a request to you as a reader to do anything other than just remember the given information for future reference. It is not an exercise where they ask you to show that it is linear, or anything like that. However, that kind of request may come in the next sentence, depending on what kind of text you're reading.

That being said, being actively engaged in whatever text you're reading, and *check* that it is linear like they claim is a good habit to get into. Even though the text itself isn't asking you to do that. Eventually, will have done such checks so many times that you see it's linear as soon as you've read the symbols on the page. At least for a simple example such as this.

**Post edit:** Now that you have added the actual exercise to your question, we can be a bit more explicit. This is what they want to use $T$ for. This is the point where you are actually asked to actively do something. In this case, take the $T$ as described, and find out which elements of $\Bbb R^3$ are mapped to the origin in $\Bbb R^2$. Said differently, find all $x,y,z$ that satisfy the equations
$$
\cases{y+z=0\\y-z=0}
$$
We have three unknowns and two equations, so there ought to be many solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the question is perfectly answered by Arthur , they have already defined the linear transformation

For the second part it is all the set of points {${(k,0,0)|k \in R}$}. Since the y,z components are getting reduced to zero. You can easily verify the Rank nullity theorem here.

Comment: What second part of the question?\

Comment: @PierreCarre to find kernel of the linear transformaton.

Comment: Totally missed it! I think it was not part of the original question...